sound in/out stop working after audacity
After using Audacity for a few hours the sound from the speakers/headphones stops working. I only can hear a very low sound from one speaker of the headphones with maximum amplification. The speakers don't give any sound at all except a very short time (0.1sec) after pressing the play button, but if I look in sound settings while something is playing, the levels are changing like they should be. If I try to record any sound from internal mic/headphones/external mic/webcam, I have no output or very tiny monotonic noise.
This issue appears on Ubuntu 16.04, but then I installed Ubuntu 24.04 by erasing all the old data, but it doesn't help. The problem stays the same. It seems to me like I tried everything - editing alsa.conf, adding and commenting lines in default.pa & blacklist ,installing/reinstalling alsa, pulse audio,pavucontol, etc.
notebook-Dell Inspiron 5567
OS - Ubuntu 24.04.1, but I've tried to hear something on every release starting from 16.04 to 24.04, but got all the same.
sound card - HDA Intel PCH, chip - Realtek ALC3246.
Results of alsamixer :

Results of lspci -v | grep Audio :

